# is it possible to use Ghost CMS with Spring Boot (Java)? If not, there is some good alternatives?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ghost-blog

I have got a new task: create a custom webapp that contains also a blog in a short time period.

I'm used to work with Spring Boot for webapp as my back-end and Thymeleaf for my front-end, my question is: is it possible to bring togheter Ghost and Spring Boot?

I actually need to create my whole application in Spring Boot (Java) cause this webapp will have also other type of features beyond the blog aspect. But because I don't have a lot of time, I don't want to make the blog manually in Spring, but rather use Ghost for the blog part.

Do you think is possible? If not, then is there some good alternatives that integrates with Spring Boot?

Thank you guys

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Clijsters Hello, I looked at the links you provided. What's the problem with my question? I cannot get it... Sorry btw

Comment: Well, you are asking a "is it possible"-quastion which can easily answered with yes. But I think you don't know where and how to start. This is kinda unspecific, like the complete idea. How exactly are you planning to use ghost in that context?

Comment: Oh I got it... sorry. Anyway, I actually know how to use Spring Boot and how to create a working webapp with it. I'm glad to here that is possible to make the two things work togheter, but as you guessed I don't know what is the best way of doing it. I thought maybe to have a domain with the webapp and then a subdomain with the blog hosted on Ghost CMS, do u think is a good/working idea? In that case do you know if Ghost can get data from my personal PostgreSQL database (users login data for example)?